# Restore Solr core on server restart?

Tags: solr

When our Solr 5.5.4 server restarts, it loses any cores it was running with previously. When I try to re-create/re-add them using the original paths (via the web interface) I am told the core already exists and cannot be added. What am I missing?

Comment: Have the same problem, but Solr allows me to add the core again. When I do, the data is restored.

Answer (score 0):

Many times people misunderstand how to "restart" solr. If you want to restart your solr instance following the commands:

```
./bin/solr stop -all
./bin/solr start -p all
```

then your cores most probably won't be there after the restart, and many times you won't be even able to load them.

If however, you stop your solr this way:

```
./bin/solr stop -all
```

and then bring up each node of your cluster this way:

```
./bin/solr start -cloud -p port -s nodepath
```

then your cores will be there! For the previous command for example you may issue:

```
./bin/solr start -cloud -p 8983 -s "example/cloud/node1/solr"
```